# What can't Qml's DropArea be used?

Tags: qt, qml

1. Qml Source code

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    DropArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

2. I use the admin rights to open the program and I can't drag and drop. However, normal opening (normal permissions) can achieve drag and drop.
3. Why are they doing this, this problem has been bothering me for a long time? How should I solve it.
4. If you try it, will it be the same?
5. Environmental:

   - Qt 5.12.2
   - Compiler: MSVC 2017 64bit

Comment: If your question is _Why are they doing this_ you should better create a ticket at [https://bugreports.qt.io](https://bugreports.qt.io). Otherwise you should provide more info, like OS, Qt version and what exactly you try to drop?

Comment: @folibis Qt Version: Qt 5.12.2; Compiler: MSVC 2017 64bit

Comment: @user11376714 see this post at QT Forum https://forum.qt.io/topic/83583/drag-and-drop-not-working-on-run-as-administrator

Comment: @AdrianoCampos Very good!Thank you very much!